Replace shortened variables with their full string
I have a code written in Lua with a load of variables in a string like this:
local var={[1]= "dothis", [2]= "clevermaths", [3]= "longstring"}
than the rest of the code uses these variables in the format of var[1], var [2] all over the place.
I was to replace all the var[1]s with "dothis", the var[2]s with "clevermaths".
I started using Find and Replace in VS Code and doing each one manually, but this was taking ages as there are over 50 of them in this script alone.
I googled along the lines of "how to replace shortened variables stored in a table with their full-length values" - no help (unless I'm some sort of coding expert - which I'm not).
I joined Stackoverflow to ask you clever people very nicely for some help, bearing in mind I'm not a coder, but get by more or less by modifying, tweaking, watching youtube tutorials etc.
Sadly I have to interact with Lua code in a very specific piece of software used for my job. It makes tasks easier, but there's no resources or budget to employ someone, so it falls on my shoulders. If I can't do it, I just have to do things manually and stay late at work.

I suppose it would not make much sense to implement in your code the ability to self-change. So you have two main options: use your editor manually to change your code, or script it (whether inside your editor, or using an independent program).
I do not use VSCode but I believe you can do it using JavaScript (*), using VSCode Tasks. (You could also build an extension, but this is an overkill.)
The easiest way is to just make an independent script; it can be written in anything you want. Lua is an obvious choice because you already have a Lua table with the desired changes, but with little tweaking you can do it in any language you are comfortable with. Here's Lua script that should do what you want.
-- Set the filename of your code here
local filename = "my_script.lua"

-- Paste your lookup table here
local var = { [1] = "dothis", [2] = "clevermaths", [3] = "longstring" }

-- read the file
local file = io.open(filename, "r")
local text = file:read("a")
file:close()

-- replace each of the table entries
for i, repl in pairs(var) do
  local key = "var%[" .. i .. "%]"
  text = text:gsub(key, repl)
end

-- save the changes
file = io.open(filename, "w")
file:write(text)
file:close()

After executing this script, your file should have been updated with all the replacements you had in your lookup table.
The other poster did mention an important safety tip: whenever you are performing a large-scale change on one of your files, make sure to use version control and commit beforehand (or, at the very least, make a backup), for safety.

*) or at least, a JavaScript build system, like grunt or npm — the code itself can be any executable.

Thank you very much for your time and clear explanation. I believe this is the best way to go

Find and replace in Visual Studio Code
In Visual Studio Code you can find and replace all by

hitting Ctrl + Shift + f
Clicking on the > icon to the left of the search text



type in what you want to find in the search box and type in what you want it to be replaced with in the replace box
There is an icon to the right of the replace box, which says "Replace All (Ctrl + Alt + Enter)". You can either click on that, or use the keyboard combination it has suggested to proceed with replacing all

Explanation of your variables
var is an array, it is a variable which has elements, such as var[1], var[2] and so on.
Precautions
Before you do your find and replace all, I recommend for you to either save the folder of your project as a copy of itself, so if things turn out wrongly, you can revert to it, or, even better, use a version controlling system, such as git. If you install git and navigate to the project folder using a terminal or a cmd (depending on your OS), then you can do
git init
git add .
git commit -m "backup"

Now, do the find and replace stuff and switch back to the terminal/cmd afterwards and run
git diff

to review all the changes you generated, see whether everything is correctly set, everything is in place, etc.

OP: "I started using Find and Replace in VS Code and doing each one manually, but this was taking ages as there are over 50 of them in this script alone." They obviously know the first part of your answer, and the second part is good advice but only tangential.
